# Unpredictable results with webRequest and sendMessage APIs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-webrequest

I'm making a chrome extension that would:

1. Detect a POST request
2. Send a message to the content script that's running in the tab that made the request
3. Retrieve some data from the DOM and send it back with sendResponse

But most of the time I'm getting "undefined" as the message sent from sendResponse.

I've made a dummy extension to debug this further, and the odd part is that it only works sometimes. I wasn't able to determine the cause of this behavior after comparing the responseHeaders of the requests.

I've used this for testing, clicking on the "related searches" buttons.
https://www.gamiss.com/wholesale-cheap/buckle-leather-belt/

What am I missing here?

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": ["testContent.js"]
      }
    ],
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "webRequest",
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["testBackground.js"],
      "persistent": true
    }
}
```

testBackground.js

```
    chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(function(e){
    if(e.type === "main_frame"){

        console.log(e);

        chrome.tabs.query({
            active:true,
            currentWindow:true
        },function (tabs){
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "Hi there..."}, function (response){
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    }

},{ 
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["main_frame"]
},["responseHeaders"]
);
```

testContent.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.message == "Hi there..."){
          console.log(request.message);
        sendResponse({response: "bye bye"});
        return true;
      } else {
          sendResponse({});
      }

    });
```

Comment: You are sending a message to the currently active tab, not necessarily the one that created the request. You can use the `tabId` property of the listener's argument object to get the tab Id of the tab that made the request and send the message to that tab. Ex: `chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(function(details){ chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, ...`. See [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onResponseStarted).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the code and seem to be getting more positive results but still getting "undefined" on some requests.
I find that odd though, wouldn't the tab I'm using be the one creating the requests? Why would it be a different tab?